# Regex to detect period before @ in email address

Tags: regex, email-validation

Need regex which will detect `first.second@domain.tld`

but not detect on `([a-z0-9A-Z])@domain.tld`

valid: `abc123XYZ@domain.tld`

invalid: `abc12.de456@domain.tld`

I recognize a period is legal preceeding `@` in an email address but need to detect that condition.

Comment: how about [a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+@domain.tld

Comment: test *invalid* emails by your req: `\..*@`

Comment: Is there anything else we can do for you? [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @kaᵠ You could just upvote my answer ... :P

Comment: you can use `\.` to match the period, or you can just detect whether `isMatch([a-z0-9A-Z]*@domain.tld)` is equal to `false`

Comment: @SamIam That is a bad way to solve the problem. Properly formatted emails can be more complicated than that. See sputnick's answer for a general idea.

Comment: @jrajav op just said he needed to detect weather there was a period before the address.

Comment: @SamIam Right, but the issue here is that your solution will not only reject addresses with no period, but also many other valid email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've already validated this as a proper email address:

`\..*@`

Which means: A `.`, then a sequence of 0 or more characters, then a `@`

Comment: there you go :) didn't scroll as much as @sputnik answer is *a bit long*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this, just compare the position of the period against the at symbol:

```
// assuming there's already an `@` in $email
if (($p = strpos($email, '.')) !== false && $p < strpos($email, '@')) {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

If there's no `@` in the email address, it will not print `'invalid'` because any integer will not strictly be smaller than `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`\.(?=.*@)`  Should do the trick.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd use a lookahead here.

Comment: I used look-ahead to only capture the "." instances coming before the "@", but without actually including the "@" in my match

Comment: This regex is only being used to detect a true/false match, from what I understand, so there is no need to exclude the `@`

Comment: Maybe they highlight the problem character for the user after validation.  I don't know, just how I chose to write the answer :)